# Power BI- Need to show data from latest week day

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, daxstudio

I have a column that displays data from the function today-1 where it shows yesterdays data.  I placed it in a filter to only show the "true" values.  The issue I am having is I need to show yesterdays data but I need to exclude the weekend. Example: Today is Monday and I need to show Friday's data not Sunday's as there isn't any.   Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

The logic for this is simple. If today is a Monday, show the data for today - 3, else show the data for today -1.

```
=if(weekday(Table[DateColumn])=2,Today()-3,Today())
```

Check out the Weekday() DAX function documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/weekday-function-dax

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.